# My twitter search is only returning 1 result

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am currently trying to find tweets that mention a twitter user for example @Google. I am trying to get a list of tweets that mention @Google. I have searched my query on twitter, and I have received results, however when I use tweepy it only brings back one row. I am using Google as an example here, it is not the actual account I am searching for mentions of.

I have tried other searches and they seem to bring back results with tweepy, however this is weird as there are definitely plenty of tweets mentioning @Google.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q="@Google",
                           count=100,
                           result_type="recent",
                           include_entities=True,
                           lang="en").items():
    print("result found")
```

I am expecting more than one result to come back, from doing a search on twitter for @Google you can get loads of mentions,so I am expecting to at least a decent subset of those mentions.

Comment: Try to print the len of items. `items = tweepy.Cursor(...).items() print(len(items)) `. What do you get?

Comment: @balderman TypeError: object of type 'ItemIterator' has no len()

Comment: Try: `items = tweepy.Cursor(...).items() print(len(list(items))) `

Comment: @balderman Still getting one, I know for sure that there are more than 1 results.

Comment: OK. But now we are sure you only get 1 entry back. Try to remove  none mandatory arguments from the Cursor. Example: remove result_type,count,etc

Comment: Why do you use @Google and not just Google?

Comment: @balderman I will try that as well.

Comment: @balderman Just Google brings back 17 results now, But I know there are way more than that...

Comment: We have a progress :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190772/discussion-between-bashir-and-balderman).

Comment: Have you tried to remove the count? I don't think it's used for api.search anymore. Remove it, and try putting the limit in the .items() (if you want the limit) http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#help-methods http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.7.0/cursor_tutorial.html Remove 'result_type' as well as I don't believe this is needed either.